# I want make an Encrypted database(SQLite) file in the sdcard?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I can create a **Database_name.sqlite** file in the sdcard but what I want is that whenever I create the database file, it'll be generated in an encrypted format, means that no one can read that file by gingo through "SQlite Manager " or any other way.

So, what should I do to achieve this?

Comment: I think you need to do a bit of studying: 1) any file you put on a device can be comprised. There is really no safe bet on this matter. 2) you can encrypt and decrypt the contents of your of your table using standard crypto 3) a db or file on the device might not be the strongest security method: web views,etc might be better.

Comment: I can encrypted the data which is going into the datbase but the thing is thing is this : what should I do to change the file format like "DB_name.sqlite" to "DB_name.sqlite.encrypt" so , no one other person use that file @cbrulak

Comment: what would that do for you? if someone roots the device it won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you want is on this page : 
[SQLCipher for Android Application Integration](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/)

Comment: i'll try this way and let u know about it ... thanks for the help

Comment: Sqlcipher is pretty awesome.  best of luck.  Also check out commonsware's (mark murphy) LoaderEx project, specifically the SQLiteCursorLoader [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) for more.  It too, I hope, will prove useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as encrypted sqlite database in built-in android support.  If you need any sort of encryption, you'll need to deal with it yourself.  One way of achieving it would be to create the database in the internal storage for your app for reading-writing with "private" access and use that file in your app.  When your app finishes, you encrypt the db file and copy it onto sd card.  When you need to access it again, you decrypt it to your internal storage again and work with it before re-encrypting it back to the sdcard.  This may not work if your database is large as you may not have enough space on the internal storage.

The other (a lot more complicated) alternative is to create the database and encrypt the file before saving it to the sd card.  Then when you need to access it, you decrypt it into memory and work with internal representation of it in memory before re-encrypting onto the sd card.  The issue here is that you have even less available memory than on the internal storage - but the operations may be a lot faster.

Finally, there are some external libraries, e.g. SQLCipher, which take the brunt of the hard work away from you, however internally they all use the same logic.

Whichever way you choose, remember that dealing with encrypted databases is slower than with non-encrypted ones.  If you have a large database, your performance hit may be significant, possibly to the point of making your app unusable.